# "Sanitize" RSS to become human readable

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, xml

I got an RSS (XML) file and would like to convert it to a JSON file with human readable text (no formatting). 
(perhaps sanitize isn't the right search term?)

An example of the XML looks like this

```
<description>&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;&lt;img alt=&quot;&quot;
 src=&quot;/site/sites/default/files/ReligionUN.png&quot; 
 style=&quot;width: 43px; height: 34px; float: left;&quot; 
 /&gt;June 20&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;br /&gt;
 &amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;
  &lt;p&gt;The UN World Refugee Day was agreed upon in 2001 in
 connection with the celebration of the Refugee Convention&amp;
 #39;s fiftieth anniversary. The date was chosen because the 
 Organization of African Unity already celebrated Africa Refugee 
 Day on June 20.&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;
 &lt;p&gt;The Holiday Calendar is sponsered by:&lt;/p&gt;
 &lt;p&gt;&lt;img alt=&quot;&quot; p=&quot;&quot;
 src=&quot;/site/sites/default/files/alle_logoer_800x600.png&quot;
 style=&quot;width: 800px; height: 600px;&quot; /&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
</description>
```

What I want to achieve is the following:

```
"description": "December 18\nThe UN International Migrants' Day
  marks the adoption of the International Migrant Workers Convention
  on December 18, 1990.\nThe UN wished to emphasize that
  transnational migration is a growing phenomenon, which can
  contribute to growth and development across the world provided that
  the international community assure migrants' rights.\n\nThe Holiday 
  Calendar is sponsered by:\n"
```

I need to clean up the text on either the XML or JSON (prefer the first one). With the following code:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const convert = require('xml-js')
const _ = require('lodash')
const striptags = require('striptags')

const xmlstr = fs.readFileSync('./english.xml', 'utf8')

const json_html = convert.xml2json(xmlstr, { compact: true, spaces: 4 })

const json_stripped = striptags(
  _.replace(json_html, new RegExp('&nbsp;', 'g'), '')
)

fs.writeFileSync('./english.json', json_stripped)
```

I got so far

```
"description": "December 18\n\nThe UN International Migrants&#39; 
  Day marks the adoption of the International Migrant Workers
  Convention on December 18, 1990.\nThe UN wished to emphasize that
  transnational migration is a growing phenomenon, which can
  contribute to growth and development across the world provided that
  the international community assure migrants&#39; rights.\nThe
  Holiday Calendar is sponsered by:\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"
```

It's almost there but as you can see I still struggle finding out how to replace things like `&nbsp;`, `&#39;` etc and shrink down multiple line breaks to single line breaks..

Comment: Do you mean that you want to strip HTML from the content? Could you show an example of the result you want?

Answer (score 1):

You want to unescape/decode html. there are a bunch of packages for it.

Like [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-entities)

```
console.log(entities.decode('&lt;&gt;&quot;&apos;&amp;&copy;&reg;&#8710;')); // <>"'&&copy;&reg;∆
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code did the job

```
const fs = require('fs')
const convert = require('xml-js')
const Entities = require('html-entities').AllHtmlEntities
const striptags = require('striptags')

const xmlstr = fs.readFileSync('./rss.xml', 'utf8')

const json_html = convert.xml2json(xmlstr.replace(/&amp;quot;/g, "'"), { compact: true, spaces: 4 })

const entities = new Entities()

const json_stripped = striptags(entities.decode(json_html))

fs.writeFileSync('./rss.json', json_stripped)
```